# poolmon.exe: 32bit versions

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, drivers

I am debugging a leak using poolmon.exe.  I have 2 versions, one from xp install disk, one from a Win2003 kit.  Some of the Microsoft documentation mentions options that my poolmon(s) do not support (/c /g I believe), I suspect that there are new versions of poolmon.exe.  I need 32bit flavor.  I am not a MSDN subscriber, I do not have access to Windows DDK nor WDK.  I have Vista Ultimate SP1 DVD, but a quick search found no poolmon.  I welcome any hints on whether there is a newer 32bit poolmon and on how to get it.  TIA, Radim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=96a35011-fd83-419d-939b-9a772ea2df90&DisplayLang=en) are the latest I was able to find at Microsoft. Not sure if they are the same that you have. I have MSDN, I will check and post back.

**Addendum:** Could not find anything else on MSDN. I only have access to OS/Applications, not the developer part.

Comment: This is newer than mine, thank you!  This is Server2003 SP2, I had SP1 or no SP.

Answer (score 0):

The Windows 2003 SP1 DDK is available [here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/9/0/f/90f019ac-8243-48d3-91cf-81fc4093ecfd/1830_usa_ddk.iso): This should give you a 32 bit version.